# Order customers based on the purchases sum

Tags: sql

I have this  SQL

```
SELECT customers.first_name 
FROM customers 
INNER JOIN orders ON customer.id = orders.customer_id
GROUP BY first_name
HAVING SUM(orders.price) > 100;
```

But I want all customers to be listed in a table from the highest purchase price of their order to the lowest.

Comment: please add which database you are using with version also add data from sporsce and result , so that it is clear what you want sorted and how

Comment: `SELECT customers.first_name FROM customers 
INNER JOIN orders ON customers.id = orders.customer_id
GROUP BY first_name ORDER BY SUM(orders.price) DESC;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use next simple `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT customers.first_name, SUM(orders.price) orders_price 
FROM customers  
INNER JOIN orders ON customers.id = orders.customer_id 
GROUP BY first_name 
ORDER BY orders_price DESC;
```

[MySQL order by fiddfe](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=3bd7ce26b1fc468cb81778ed8b0aa35c&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)

Also you can use `LEFT JOIN` and `COALESCE` function for select customers without orders:

```
SELECT 
    customers.first_name, 
    COALESCE(SUM(orders.price), 0) orders_price FROM customers  
LEFT JOIN orders ON customers.id = orders.customer_id 
GROUP BY first_name 
ORDER BY orders_price DESC;
```

[MySQL LEFT JOIN & COALESCE](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=8f8ab5f37e18bb0cb05229d0b1ffaa3c&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)